# What is this palm?

Tags: identification, houseplants, palm

There is a palm for sale. The seller haven't specified what sort of palm is that.

I suppose this could be:

- Either an Areca palm, which requires bright indirect light and should be kept moist at all times,
- Or a Kentia palm which, quite the opposite, requires low light and should stay dry between waterings.
- Or something else?

Given the yellow bamboo-like stems, I suppose it's an Areca palm? Is it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My money is on Areca (dypsis lutescens).